# How to send form information from website to a phone number's message inbox?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mobile, sms

Is it possible to send form information from a website to a phone number's message inbox?
There is a mobile website that I'm working on, and the client has asked for something like that. He wishes to receive the form information a user fills up in his website directly into his phone's native SMS inbox.
I'd be glad if anyone would guide me through this. Thanks!

Comment: look into twilio: https://www.twilio.com/sms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly? No.

You can use either:

- A general SMS Gateway service (which you will have to pay for)
- A GSM modem connected to the server (which you will have to get a contract for)
- A gateway service particular to the cellular provider of your client (some offer email to SMS gateways)

Answer (score 1):

PHP by itself does not offer SMS functionality that'd help you send SMS.

The available options are:

- Using a SMS Gateway Provider
- Using a GSM modem
- Use a direct connection to a wireless network, which will require some strong negotiating and a whole lot of money

Here's a good [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php/) on NetTuts explaining everything (almost) you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's only going to be the client receiving this and you know their carrier information, **you don't need to pay money to do this**! You can just send the data using php's `mail` function directly to the client's SMS inbox. To do this most carriers have an email address to send to. For example, to send to 555-555-5555 on at&t, just use php's `mail` function with the to parameter set to: `5555555555@txt.att.net`. I have done this in the past and it works great.

This is only a good solution in this instance because you know the client's carrier and don't particularly care about it sending from the same number each time; however, if you were going to be using SMS to text users, then you should be using a service like twilio.

Read this site for a list of addresses: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27051/use-email-to-send-text-messages-sms-to-mobile-phones-for-free/